# Visual Studio Express 2017 - Visual Bug

Tags: visual-studio-express

I have searched quite a bit to find out what is going wrong but cannot find any relevant information, here is what my Visual Studio Express 2017 looks like in WPF App (.Net Framework 4.6.1).

[image]

Comment: And exactly which part is not right? What have you tried to reset them?

Comment: @zerocukor287 the black rectangles in my window, the black bars in my properties window. I disabled a lot of graphical enhancements from the options but it didn't do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a theme issue found in the latest version of Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2017, changing the theme to Dark or Light instead will fix this visual bug.